# How to know if a group of points makes a non-convex shape?

Tags: graphics, three.js, geometry

I would like to make a triangulation of a polygon in THREE.JS represented by group of 2d points.
Is there a test i can make on array of 2d points that will tell whether the group of points make a convex shape or non-convex shape?
Is there a best practice for this kind of triangulation that will work well both for convex and non-convex shapes?

Comment: You can build convex hull around any point set. Of course, some sets are better represented by non-convex tracing like alpha shapes.

Comment: Are the points ordered or are they just scattered in space? For scattered points, finding *a*  polygon is highly ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a 2D shape defined by a contour, a sequence of 2D vectors in CCW order. A shape is convex if all pairs of consecutive edges form a left (counterclockwise) circuit. You can verify this by representing two edges as a triple of points and then call `leftOn()` which returns true iff the mentioned left property is given or if the points are collinear.

```
function leftOn( a, b, c ) {

    return area2( a, b, c ) >= 0;

}

function area2( a, b, c ) {

    return ( ( c.x - a.x ) * ( b.y - a.y ) ) - ( ( b.x - a.x ) * ( c.y - a.y ) );

}
```

You can read more about this approach in: *Computational Geometry in C, Joseph O'Rourke*